# subprocess module works but not exactly working

Tags: python, subprocess, maya

I am trying to replace the `os.system` with subprocess module (referencing from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)), however though it seems to work (displaying the result in the script editor) but it is actually not working.

```
def convert_text(inImg, outImg, texImg):
    if not os.path.exists(texImg):
        Image.open(inImg).save(outImg)
        #os.system('/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake ' + outImg + ' ' + texImg)
        subprocess.Popen("/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake" + outImg + " " + texImg, shell = True)
        os.remove(outImg)
        print "Done converting " + inImg
```

The above code is supposed to look for any image files, converting it into .tif then followed by .tex. Though the results may state `Done converting /user_data/texture/testTexture_01.tga`, in actual fact there isn't any .tex files to be found in the directory. (there should be .tex files located at /user_data/texture, within where the image file is located)

I also tried to write it as `subprocess.Popen('/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake %s %s'% (outImg, texImg), shell = True)` but it ain't working.

EDIT: I am running the following code in Maya as I am implementing that in that software

Am I doing it wrong in some ways?

Comment: @suhail I am not seeing any errors, even as I have turned on `echo all commands` since I am using it in Maya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Popen` is non-blocking, so it's not actually complete when the call returns. Because you're removing `outImg` right after the `Popen` call starts, the command is probably failing.  Use `subprocess.call` instead, which will block until the command is finished:

```
subprocess.call(["/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake", outImg, texImg])
```

Comment: Cool, it works!! By the way, can I also that there is a subprocess for `os.remove` too?

Comment: @dissidia `os.remove` is the right method to use for file removal. In general, you should only use the `subprocess` module to do something when there's no native method in the standard library.

Comment: Apologize for the lack of understanding. Just thought that if there is a subprocess module for `os.system`, I thought `os.remove` will have one as well, afterall they are sharing `os` modules, you see... However can I ask what you mean in your latter sentence - `when there's no native method in the standard library`?

Comment: @dissidia The `subprocess` module is designed a replacement for all other methods and modules that are used to run sub-processes in Python (examples include `os.system`, `os.popen`, `os.spawn*`, the `commands` module). `os.remove` can remove a file without needing to launch a sub-process at all. Launching a sub-process has a lot of overhead, so you should always prefer using methods that don't involve doing it if they're available (this is what I meant by "native").

Answer (score 3):

`subprocess.Popen` takes a list of arguments. ie try:

```
subprocess.Popen(["/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake", outImg, texImg])
```

update: removed `shell=True`

Comment: Don't use `shell = True` if there's any chance your filenames might have spaces, quotation marks, asterisks, etc. in them. Basically, just don't use `shell = True` until you *really* know what you're doing. It's a common source of bugs and security holes.

Comment: @suhall It does not seems to be working for me as well

Comment: If you use `shell=True`, you should pass the command as a string, not a list. However, you generally shouldn't use `shell=True`, as already noted.

Answer (score 1):

As @suhail said, `Popen` takes a list of arguments, but (as of right now) his example code is wrong. It should look like this:

```
#os.system('/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake ' + outImg + ' ' + texImg)
subprocess.Popen(["/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake", outImg, texImg])
```

You should **not** use `shell = True` unless you've verified that outImg and texImg have no characters with special meaning to the shell (quote marks, **spaces**, asterisks, etc.) in them. With `shell = True`, those characters would be processed by the shell, and the results will probably not be what you expect. What you want is `shell = False` (which is the default), so that filenames with quote marks, spaces, etc. will be properly backslash-escaped before being passed to the shell.

**UPDATE**: You probably want to use `subprocess.call()`, not `subprocess.Popen()`. See [the `subprocess` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module): `call()` will wait for the command to complete, then return the integer return code (which will be 0 if no errors occurred). You should capture that return code and test it, then only delete `outImg` if there were no errors. E.g.,:

```
def convert_text(inImg, outImg, texImg):
    if not os.path.exists(texImg):
        Image.open(inImg).save(outImg)
        #os.system('/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake ' + outImg + ' ' + texImg)
        retcode = subprocess.call("/apps/Linux64/prman-18.0/bin/txmake", outImg, texImg)
        if (retcode == 0):
            os.remove(outImg)
        else:
            print "txmake returned error code " + str(retcode)
        print "Done converting " + inImg
```

Read the documentation for more details on what you can do with `call()`.

Comment: It does not seems to be working, or should I be using other command?

Comment: @dissidia - Sorry, I should have recommended `subprocess.call()` instead of `Popen()`. That's the function to use if you want to say "Just run this external program and get back to me when it's finished", which is what your code needs.

Comment: I have a question though, like what exactly is the difference between `Popen` and `call` though? How will I know when to use it?

Comment: @dissidia - Read the docs if you want to know the differences in detail; I can only cover the broad strokes. Basically, `call` waits for the process to run before it returns; `Popen` starts the external process then returns immediately while the process is still running, returning a [Popen object](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) that lets you interact with the external process (send data to its stdin, read its stdout or stderr, and so on). So if you need to fire off the process and do nothing else, use `call`. If you need to interact with it, use `Popen`.